# Probabilistic Measure over Function Space

Tags: probability, measure-theory, optimization

I was reading an article on probabilistic global optimization and came across following equation which defines probabilistic measure over function space.

$$p_{\min }(x) \equiv p[x=\arg \min f(x)]=\int_{f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}} p(f) \prod_{\tilde{x} \in I \atop \tilde{x} \neq x} \theta[f(\tilde{x})-f(x)] \mathrm{d} f$$

Now the more confusion part is that author mentions that **the exact meaning of infinite product over the entire domain I in this equation should be intuitively clear**

Can someone please explain why are we taking infinite product over the functions will determine probability  that the value of f at x is lower than at any other ˜x ∈ I ?

This is the link to the equation 1 in [journal](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/hennig12a/hennig12a.pdf).

Comment: "The exact meaning of the “infinite product” over the entire
domain I in this equation should be intuitively clear, *but is defined properly in the Appendix*". You seemed to have left off from that quote that the precise definition is contained in the appendix of the paper, as a certain limiting process. Did you read the appendix?

Comment: "In words: The “infinite product” is meant to be the limit of finite-dimensional integrals with an increasing number of factors and dimensions, where this limit exists. In doing so, we have sidestepped
the issue of whether this limit exists for any particular Gaussian process (kernel function). We do
so because the theory of suprema of stochastic processes is highly nontrivial. We refer the reader to
a friendly but demanding introduction to the topic by Adler (1990). From our applied standpoint,
the issue of whether (8) is well defined for a particular Gaussian prior is secondary..."

Comment: Yes I read the Appendix, but didnt grasp the intituition as to why and how infinite product is the limit of the integrals.

Comment: @NapD.Lover could you please care to check this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393907/bayesian-probability-evaluation-of-an-expression)